# Itemtap and listening Event function Sencha Touch 2 List

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Hi all am finding it difficult to set set a call back function, i have a list and in my controller, am trying to listen to each of the items in the list so that once each item is being taped, it will display a map with a marker pointing at the specified lat and log specified in my store for that  particular item. i was thinking an itemtap even will be the best for this, but i don't know how to set it up in my controller.

This my store:

```
Ext.define('List.store.Presidents', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

config : {
    model : 'List.model.President',
    sorters : 'lastName',
    storeId: 'contactmap',
    grouper : function(record) {
        return record.get('lastName')[0];
    },

    data : [{
        firstName : "Ikhlas HQ",
        lastName : "Tower 11A, Avenue 5, Bangsar South, No.8 Jalan Kerinchi 59200 Kuala Lumpur",
        lat : 3.110649,
        lng : 101.664991,
        id: '200',
    },
    {
        firstName : "PEJABAT WILAYAH SELANGOR",
        lastName : "No. 97, 97-1 & 97-2, Jalan Mahogani 5/KS7, Ambang Botanic, 41200 Klang, Selangor",
        lat : 3.003384,
        log : 101.45256,
        id: '001',
    },]}
});
```

This my Controller:

```
Ext.define('List.controller.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
config: {
    refs: {
        main: 'mainpanel',
      },
    control: {
        'presidentlist': {
            disclose: 'showDetail'
        },
     } },
showDetail: function(list, record) {
            this.getMain().push({
                xtype: 'presidentdetail',
                title: record.fullName(),
                data: record.getData(),
listeners: {
    itemtap : function(component, map, geo, eOpts) {
                     var contactmap = Ext.getStore('contactmap'); 

                contactmap.load({ 
                    callback:function(records,map,componet,lad,log){
                        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(); 
                 }
                 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: map
                        });

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: 'Working Fine'
                        });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                });

                },
              }, 
        })
     },
});
```

Hope i can get some help here to proceed am stuck at this point. thanks

Comment: You've asked 16 question, 13 of them have been answered and you only accepted 3 of them. So when your question gets answered, either the answer is correct and then accept it, or it's not and then provide more information about your problem or else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.define('List.controller.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
config: {
    refs: {
        myList: 'presidentlist', // 'presidentlist' is xtype of your list
      },
    control: {
        myList: {
            itemtap: 'onMyListItemTap'
        },
     }
},
onMyListItemTap: function(list, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
  // some functionality here
  var myLat = record.data.lat;  // etc.
  var myLng = record.data.lng;  // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dmytro, am really have the problem setting up logic to call up the lat and log from my store so that once each of   the item in the list is taped it show the marker on the map.i manage to get it working by setting the location manually in my controller with this codes. var position = new google.maps.LatLng(5.978132,116.072617);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: position,
map: map
}); this only set just 1 location meaning all the items in the list is set to 1 location. how do i load it dynamically so that each item have diffrnt location on map when its taped.

Comment: when you define your presidentlist you has to initialize store configuration in it. (config: {store: 'Presidents'}). onMyListItemTap function has parameter "record". This parameter has all data for exactly one item you have tapped. (var myLat = record.data.lat;)

Comment: also you have typo in store: lng vs log,

Comment: Hi Dmytro, i have corrected the typo error in my store, secondly i have initialize the store config with (config: {store: 'Presidents'}) but its still not working, i guess its a logical problem from my controller, please help me look into this again.the below codes are my controller and my current store.

Comment: try to define itemtap logic in controller but not while creating presidentdetail object. Your code is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

My Controller:

```
Ext.define('List.controller.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
config: {
refs: {
    main: 'mainpanel',
  },
control: {
    myList: {
        itemtap: 'onMyListItemTap'
    },
    'presidentlist': {
            disclose: 'showDetail'
        },
 }
},
showDetail: function(list, record) {
            this.getMain().push({
                xtype: 'presidentdetail',
                title: record.fullName(),

onMyListItemTap: function(list, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng();

    var myLat = record.data.lat;  
    var myLng = record.data.lng;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: map
                        });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        });

                    setTimeout(function() {
                    map.panTo(position);
                        }, 1000);
},
});
 },
});
```

My Store:

```
Ext.define('List.store.Presidents', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

config : {
    model : 'List.model.President',
    sorters : 'lastName',
    storeId: 'contactmap',
    grouper : function(record) {
        return record.get('lastName')[0];
    },

    data : [{
        firstName : "Ikhlas HQ",
        lastName : "Tower 11A, Avenue 5, Bangsar South, No.8 Jalan Kerinchi 59200 Kuala Lumpur",
        lat : 3.110649,
        log : 101.664991,
        id: '200',
    },
    {
        firstName : "PEJABAT WILAYAH SELANGOR",
        lastName : "No. 97, 97-1 & 97-2, Jalan Mahogani 5/KS7, Ambang Botanic, 41200 Klang, Selangor",
        lat : 3.003384,
        log : 101.45256,
        id: '001',
    }, {
        firstName : "PEJABAT WILAYAH KEDAH",
        lastName : "57, Jalan Lagenda 3, Legenda Heights, 08000, Sungai Petani, Kedah Darul Aman",
        lat : 5.657754,
        log : 100.50014,
        id: '002',
    },] 
},
});
```

My Model:

```
Ext.define('List.model.President', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
config : {
    store: 'Presidents',
    fields : ['firstName', 'middleInitial', 'lastName', 'lat', 'log', 'id']
},
fullName : function() {
    var d = this.data, names = [d.firstName, (!d.middleInitial ? "" : d.middleInitial + "."), d.id];
    return names.join(" ");
}
});
```